# Andengine Friction between bodies

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I face strange behavior with no friction between two bodies static and dynamic. I declare bodies in follow code(code in kotlin):

```
val WALL_FIXTURE_DEF  = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0f, 0f, 50f)
val ground = Rectangle(this.mCameraWidth / 2, wallWidth / 2 , this.mCameraWidth, wallWidth, this.vertexBufferObjectManager)
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody, WALL_FIXTURE_DEF)
...
this.mBall = UniformColorSprite(this.mCameraWidth / 2, this.mCameraHeight /2 , TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, mBallTextureRegion, this.vertexBufferObjectManager)
val body: Body
val objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(100f, 0.3f, 10f, false, CATEGORYBIT_CIRCLE, MASKBITS_CIRCLE, 0)
body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, this.mBall, BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef)           
this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(PhysicsConnector(this.mBall, body, true, true))
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Seems it is ok when I added setFixedRotation(true) to body. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If the second body is circle it is getting some *torque* that can make an impression that fiction of not working when it is actually working and causes torque.

When you are setting `setFixedRotation` you are prevent circleBody of rolling and then you can observe the fiction.

Try to change circleBody to polygon and see what will happen.